# Page not loading into modal Dialog div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm scratching my head as to why a modal dialog I've built is not loading the page specified by the 'href' attribute in an anchor tag.

**Javascript:**

```
// let's build an info dialog!
    $( '.infolink' ).each(function() {
        var $page = $(this);
        var url = $page.attr('href');
        var $docviewer = $('<div class="stuffHolder"></div>')
        .dialog({
            open: function() {
                $( '.stuffHolder' ).load(url);
            },
            title: "Additional Information",
            position: { my: "center top", at: "center top", of: "#trbl" },
            show: true, //animates a fade in for the window
            autoOpen: false, //dialogs do not open by default
            width: 600, //sets dialog width
            height: 600, //sets dialog height
            modal: true, //disables everything below the dialog until dialog is closed
            buttons: {
                "Close Document": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                     }
            }
        });
        $page.click(function() {
            $docviewer.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    }); // end info dialog
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="test.html" class="infolink">Load test page into modal dialog</a>
```

The dialog loads just fine, but it's completely empty on load.

Comment: Are you sure the path of your test.html is correct?

Comment: @entiendoNull - yes, the path to the html file is correct. The file is in the same folder as the page calling for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
open: function() {
            $( '.stuffHolder' ).load(url);
        },
```

into:

```
open: function() {
            $docviewer.load(url);
        },
```

You can also try appending the $docviewer into the body before opening the dialog. It might help.

Comment: Using `$docviewer.load(url);` in place of `$( '.stuffHolder' ).load(url);` didn't appear to change anything.

Comment: try appending $docviewer to the body before you open the dialog.

Comment: I'm not quite following what you're suggesting I do. What do you mean by 'append $docviewer to the body'?

Comment: After searching a bit, I found this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/559452/loadplushtmlpluspageplusinplusdivplustagplususingp . Go through the first solution. I am not sure about it's relevance to your problem.